# How to solve this problem of slowness in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, performance-testing

In my company we have a website that is developed with ASP .NET 4.5.2 technology

The site has always had an optimal performance and when I say this is that the domain does not take 1 second to load or the waiting times to do activities that use the database do not spend 5 seconds.

On the site, payment receipts are printed, people's information is consulted, etc. but recently a new functionality was implemented and it is an Survey, which costs 228 questions.

The questions are answered through RadiobuttonList to speed up the process and each time the control is pressed the answer is saved in the database to always maintain the status of the survey in which the user is, this makes per minute receive approximately 11 transactions in the database, a WebMethod is also used to validate the questions synchronously and a WCF is used to connect to the database layer (SQL Server 2014 Express)

From the first day that this functionality was implemented, complaints were received from users because they received errors **502 Proxy Error** or the site took almost 2 minutes or more to load each form, sometimes I had to restart the IIS service so that everything returns to normality

At the beginning, the survey functionality used HttpContext.Current.Session to save the status of the user's survey, that is, to know which questions it has answered and which ones were still to be answered, I decided to change this to a protected static object at the level of the suspicious form that this was the cause.

It has not worked and still the problem of slowness, curiously the database server is normal and is not affected, at this time I decided to find a way to outline the performance of the web server to know how many people connect to the application, through the Performance Monitor and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/802642/how-to-find-the-current-number-of-https-connections-to-iis) coincided in that the number of people connected is an average of 50, where suddenly it goes up to 90 or goes down to 20. Is this the correct way to know the number of users connected to my application? (The pink line indicates the number of *Current Connections*)

[image]

**But what kind of server do I have?**

Well, it's really a virtualized machine (VMWare) with:

- Processor Intel Xeon CPU E3-1220 v5 @ 3.00GHz (2 processors)
- 4.00 GB of memory
- System x64 bits and is a Windows 10 Pro Operating System
- IIS 10.0

The fact that you do not even have a server operating system is the cause of the problem?

Does this have to do with the bandwidth used by the server?

Should I do some configuration in IIS or the Web.config of my application to optimize the performance?

Comment: Open your website in Chrome and open the Developer Tools window and find out which requests are slow - then attach a debugger and profiler to your application-pool (w3wp) process and find out where it's getting slowed down. From what you've written, I think the problem is your webpage is simply doing too many synchronous things to be completed within a short period time (e.g. ~100ms - HTML responses should complete in under 300ms for a decent user-experience).

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope in your code and more importantly are you catching and logging exceptions?

Comment: If I use it, does TransactionScope have anything to do with it?

Comment: We had no solution, the same day that I asked this question we had to buy a new server